# colourize the first part of each line

Tags: sed, colors, highlighting

I have some chat logs like:

```
(15:12:56) rubo77: mist migration
(15:05:22) hans: ist hugo da?
(15:36:13) rubo77: test
(13:30:15) rubo77: what are the access data?
(15:06:38) someone@jabber.ccc.de: user :  test@test.de (https://somewhere.de:8080/index.php#)
(15:06:38) someone@jabber.ccc.de: password :  test
```

How can I replace this using `sed` so the usernames will be in a different color?

Or is there a simpler tool than `sed`?

Comment: Do you want all user-names the same colour, if so grep --color=always can do it. You don't need to worry about the codes to set the colour.

Comment: It would be cool to have all usernames in different colors, but that seems to be hard to solve. since I cannot predict the usernames to come

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this:

```
sed 's/) \(.*\):/) \x1b[31m\1\x1b[0m:/'
```

for example:

```
cat 1| sed 's/) \(.*\):/) \x1b[31m\1\x1b[0m:/'
```

VERSION 2:

```
COLOR=32
sed 's/) \(.*\):/) \x1b['${COLOR}'m\1\x1b[0m:/'
```

you can change color number

VERSION 3:

```
COLOR=32
sed 's/) \([[:alpha:][:digit:][:space:]@\.]*\):/) \x1b['${COLOR}'m\1\x1b[0m:/1'
```

Comment: I used your code here too: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3042/1974

Answer (score 1):

`awk` should be the simplest:

```
awk '{$2="\033[01;31m"$2"\033[00m"; print $0}' logfile
```

Comment: username is between `)` and `:` ! if user name content SPACE your code break!

Comment: @Babyy usernames usually don't have spaces

Comment: @chaos: looks like *chat* logs, so I'd reckon they can contain all sorts of characters. Of course it would have been nice of the OP to point this out beforehand, not afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you want to do (multi-user coloring) is possible, but is not entirely simple.

You can create a very long sed expression (use `;`) that performs the requested action;
This is EXACTLY what this shell script is doing, to represent used activity on a cluster:
http://fotis.web.cern.ch/fotis/QTOP/

(the last section of the screenshots, shows an instance of the use-case described)

the idea is to parse qtop.colormap, compile it to a sed expression and then use that.

Caveat: because of using shell scripting and deep sed expressions it has very poor maintainability, in regards software engineering. But you can certainly do it.

Comment: qtop doesn't seem to run on my Ubuntu 14.04: `/usr/bin/qtop: line 161: /usr/bin/qstat: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @rubo77: that won't work unless you have a PBS-like queueing system configured. If you do, I'd rather suggest you use the python alternative to the above code, available via pip install qtop or here: https://github.com/qtop/qtop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ccze` to colourize the output.

It is not optimized for this case, but gives a lot of beautiful patterns.